# .get trying to catch length and append to element

Tags: jquery, get

```
$('.statused tr .tcr').after('<td class="tc2"><span class="views">0</span> Users  Viewing</td>');
  var href = $('.statused .hierarchy a.forumtitle').attr('href');
    $.get(href , function(data) { 
         var elem = $(data);
         var count = $('.listeduser a').length;
       $('.views').html(elem.find());
     }, 'html');
```

Ok so as you can see I am trying to get the `length` of the a hrefs on each href. I just can't figure out how to write the last bit on `$('.views').html(elem.find());` I guess this bit is confusing me really. I have a simple markup

http://jsbin.com/ijidob/1/

Easier to see there. I just need to get the count on each href per tr.

Someone have any ideas how to fix the last line to run the code correctly?

Comment: Can you rephrase that?

Comment: Just can't figure out how to write the line `$('.views').html(elem.find());` look at the jsbin you'll see what I am doing. The line ` var count = $('.listeduser a').length;` needs to be what the data fetched is, and then places it per tr that there is.